# Specflow step definition classes in different projects

Tags: specflow

Is it possible to have two step definition classes with first being in one namespace/project, and second in another one?
I have like this:

My test project which I run:
namespace: ABZ.ExcelTest
class name: ABZ.ExcelTest.ExcelStepDefinition

My other project which is Logic for testing:
namespace: ABZ.OfficeAddInTestLogic
class name: ABZ.OfficeAddInTestLogic.StepDefinition

I have [Binding] attribute on both my classes but this one which is not in test project 
(ABZ.OfficeAddInTestLogic.StepDefinition) cannot be found, I get NUnit error:

No matching step definition found for the step. Use the following code to create one:
...

Is it possible to have 2 step definition classes in different projects?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes it is - that feature is called External steps (see https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/blob/master/Tests/FeatureTests/ExternalSteps/ExternalSteps.feature)

What you probably are missing is an app.config setting like this:

```
<specFlow>  
<stepAssemblies>
  <stepAssembly assembly="ExternalStepsCS" />
</stepAssemblies>
```

That will look for steps in an external assembly called ExternalStepsCS in this case.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I haven't used config file to cofigure specflow. Thanks for this. :)

Answer (score 1):

I will often have a "Test Helpers" library, with common code shared between multiple test projects.  I'll have a class in this shared library, let's call it `CucumberBase`.  Then, in my actual test project, I'll have a class like this:

```c#
[Binding]
public class SomeFeatureSpecs : CucumberBase
{
    ...
}
```

Every public `CucumberBase` method that is tagged with `[Given()]`/`[When()]`/`[Then()]`/etc. gets picked up correctly in my actual test project, within the `SomeFeatureSpecs` class.  This lets me override and extend common functionality as well.